# How to pass parameters to Google Maps initmap in XSLT?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to get the position by getting the latitude and longitude from an xml document, through an xslt stylesheet. I made xslt variables which return the correct latitude and longitude when I call them (for example with xsl:value-of). But I can't seem to access the same variables in the javascript snipet. From what I read it's possible to call an xslt variable inside javascript. So I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
                                        <xsl:for-each-group select="MBMDVRs/LocatorInfo" group-by="string-join((LocationAddr/StreetNum, ' ', LocationAddr/StreetName, ' ', LocationAddr/City, ' ', LocationAddr/StateProv, ' ', LocationAddr/PostalCode), '!')">
                                                <tr style="border-collapse:collapse; font-size:inherit; text-align:center; " class="wide">
                                                    <td class="rownr{(position() + 1) mod 2}" style="width:0.95in; ">
                                                    </td> 
                                                    <td class="rownr{(position() + 1) mod 2}" style="width:2.57in; "> 
                                        <xsl:value-of select="LocationAddr/StreetNum, ' ',  LocationAddr/StreetName, ' ', LocationAddr/mbg:City,  ' ' , LocationAddr/StateProv, LocationAddr/PostalCode" />&#160;&#160;


                                <xsl:variable name="Latitude" select="LocationAddr/GEOCode/mbg:Latitude"/>
                                <xsl:variable name="Longitude" select="LocationAddr/mbg:GEOCode/Longitude"/>
                                <script>
                            function initMap(){
                                var location = {lat: parseFloat("<xsl:value-of select="$Latitude"/>"), 
                                lng: parseFloat("<xsl:value-of select="$Longitude"/>")};
                                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {zoom: 15, center: location

                            });
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: location, 
                            map: map
                            });
                    }
                            </script>
                                                        <a href="#" onclick="initMap()">Street View</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="rownr{(position() + 1) mod 2}" style="width:1.82in; "> 
                                                        <xsl:copy-of select="(//LocationTimestamp)[last()]"/>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="rownr{(position() + 1) mod 2}" style="width:1.82in; ">
                                                        <xsl:copy-of select="(//LocationTimestamp)[1]"/>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="rownr{(position() + 1) mod 2}" style="width:2.27in; ">
                                                         <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())" />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                   </xsl:for-each-group>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

I'm trying to display the result in this div:

And use this link:

And use this xml:

```
<LocatorInfo>
    <LocationAddr>
      <StreetNum>187</StreetNum>
      <StreetName>Eastern Avenue</StreetName>
      <City>Fall River</City>
      <StateProv>MA</StateProv>
      <PostalCode>02723</PostalCode>
      <Country>USA</Country>
      <GEOCode>
        <Latitude>41.694600119635915</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-71.13038416718094</Longitude>
      </GEOCode>
    </LocationAddr>
    <LocationTimestamp>4/7/2018 7:00:03 AM</LocationTimestamp>
    <LocationDistance>4.338 miles</LocationDistance>
    <Accuracy>1.985 miles</Accuracy>
  </LocatorInfo>
```

Comment: How do you use XSLT (2 or 3 as the use of `current-group()` suggests) exactly? Do you run that outside of the browser? Normally XSLT just creates a result document, for instance an HTML document, which can of course also contain Javascript code, but running the XSLT to create the HTML and rendering the HTML and executing the script are usually two completely separated steps. So how does the HTML result document with the script code look you get from XSLT? Which Javascript error do you get from which browser when rendering the HTML? Does the HTML/script work when not using XSLT?

Comment: I also wonder why you use `lat: parseFloat("<xsl:value-of select="$Latitude"/>")` and not simply `lat: <xsl:value-of select="$Latitude"/>`. That would output the Javascript code snippet `lat: 41.694600119635915` which should do just fine. Although I don't think your approach should cause problems, it just seems too complicated.

Comment: I use xslt 2.0 to transform an xml into a html, use Altova xml spy for editing and parsing. The script works well, since I applied it to the resulting html first. But I need to integrate it into the stylesheet, to not manually put it into every html I generate. The problem seems to be specifically about passing the variables. The script works when used directly into the html. And when I print the values in the xslt, the values are also correct. I also parse them to float in the script to make sure they are seen as the correct type.

Comment: I tried using it without the parseFloat, and the map didn't even display in the page.

Comment: So which script error exactly do you get from which browser exactly when you try to render the XSLT result you get from Altova XMLSpy? Or which XSLT error exactly do you get?

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCOXz4X5nolodp4aGXM-R4DVf7BkV0fDgI&callback=initMap I get a script error pointing to this url

Comment: So which error message exactly, from which browser/tool?

Comment: That's it. When I run the transformation with xml spy it says Script error, Line, Char and Code are all 0. And it just points to the API url: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCOXz4X5nolodp4aGXM-R4DVf7BkV0fDgI&callback=initMap. But there is no problem with the url, since I used it when testing the script directly on the html.

Comment: By default Altova renders the result in INternet Explored. But Google Maps Api doesn't work in IE. So I open it in Chrome. When I open the output in Chrome it just opens the map bank.

Comment: The use of XSLT and `current-group()` suggests you are perhaps trying to generate the map and/or script code various times? Are you targetting the same HTML element various times e.g. do you have a single element with `id="map"` you target with `document.getElementById("map")`? Or does your XSLT perhaps generate several elements with the same id? It might help if you show minimal but complete samples of XML, XSLT together with the generated HTML to allow others to reproduce the problem. You will  need to remove your map API key from the samples, but we need to see more details.

Comment: Added the whole foreach-group. Basically there can be more LocatorInfos in the xml with the exact same adress. So the grouping was made to display the address just once in such cases. As you can see in the div I pointed out, there is just one map id.

Comment: So does the HTML and script generated by XSLT work if there is only a single group, i.e. if you reduce the XML to have data for only one group? I am not sure what you want to achieve for several groups but spitting out several `script` elements each having a different definition of the same Javascript function `initMap` doesn't seem to make sense to me in terms of Javascript, as only the last function definition will be available to any event handler or other code later calling `initMap()`. It seems you need to refactor your Javascript code to have a callable function with the `location` arg.

Comment: It seems you are correct. After further tests, it seems the address displayed on the map is the one in the last group. What I want is to be updated with the map for each group, once you click the <a href="#" onclick="initMap()">Street View</a> element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change your Javascript code to have a function you can call to create the appropriate map and marker, so outside of any grouping you put

```
            <script>
            function showMap(targetElement, location) {
              var map = new google.maps.Map(targetElement, { zoom: 15, center: location });
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location, 
                map: map
              });
            }
            </script>
```

then inside of your grouping you use

```
 <a href="#" onclick="showMap(document.getElementById('map'), {{ lat: {GEOCode/Latitude}, lng: {GEOCode/Longitude} }}); return false;">Street View</a>
```

that should solve the problem I think, in terms of interaction of XSLT and generated script code in an HTML document.

I don't know whether it would be easier/faster to not use `new google.maps.Map` each time the function is called and instead perhaps only move the center and the marker (or delete the existing marker and create a new) in an initially created map, but here is how you would implement that first script block instead:

```
            <script>
            var map = null;
            var marker = null;

            function showMap(targetElement, location) {
              if (map != null) {
                  map.setCenter(location);
                  marker.setPosition(location);
              }
              else {
                  map = new google.maps.Map(targetElement, { zoom: 15, center: location });
                  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: location, 
                    map: map
                  });
              }
            }
            </script>
```