# Unescaped XML character when assigning value to Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

So I can't get around this. I am trying to assign an XML value to javascript in order to request a google map. This is inside a for each, so I can display a small map for each location. Please help.
  EDIT: I uploaded the whole XSL file which has some other issues, such as the mess of CSS, and accordion issues. But my main focus is the javascript issues at the bottom. The XML data being used is a dictionary of events, and I am trying to call the stored LAT and LNG so that I may produce a google map per event location. Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" version="5.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
    <title>XSL</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body style="font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive; font-weight: bold; background-image: url(png/BG01dark.jpg);
    background-size: cover; background-position: center; background-repeat: none; background-attachment: fixed;">
    <div class="container">
        <center><font style="color: white; font-size: 50px; text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #000000;">
            Impulse</font></center>
        <center><p><font style="color: white; font-size: 20px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;">
            Your friendly computer science event organizer</font></p></center>

        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <xsl:for-each select="all/*">
        <div class="panel panel-default" style="background: rgba(255,255,255.75);" >
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">
                  <xsl:if test="Type = 'Careers'">
                      <img style="background: rgba(255,255,255.75); width:45px; height:45px;
                      border: 3px solid green; border-radius: 10px; padding: 7px;"
                              src="png/career.png" alt="Careers">Careers</img>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="Type = 'Database'">
                      <img style="background: rgba(255,255,255.75); width:45px; height:45px;
                      border: 3px solid blue; border-radius: 10px; padding: 7px;"
                           src="png/database.png" alt="Database">Database</img>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="Type = 'Game Dev'">
                      <img style="background: rgba(255,255,255.75); width:45px; height:45px;
                      border: 3px solid red; border-radius: 10px; padding: 7px;"
                           src="png/gamepad.png" alt="Game Development">Game Dev</img>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="Type = 'Mobile App'">
                      <img style="background: rgba(255,255,255.75); width:45px; height:45px;
                      border: 3px solid purple; border-radius: 10px; padding: 5px;"
                           src="png/mobile.png" alt="Mobile Development">Mobile Dev</img>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="Type = 'Networking'">
                      <img style="background: rgba(255,255,255.75); width:45px; height:45px;
                      border: 3px solid yellow; border-radius: 10px; padding: 7px;"
                           src="png/networking.png" alt="Networking">Networking</img>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="Type = 'Robotics'">
                      <img style="background: rgba(255,255,255.75); width:45px; height:45px;
                      border: 3px solid #FF6D14; border-radius: 10px; padding: 7px;"
                           src="png/robot.png" alt="Robotics">Robotics</img>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="Type = 'Cyber Security'">
                      <img style="background: rgba(255,255,255.75); width:45px; height:45px;
                      border: 3px solid aqua; border-radius: 10px; padding: 7px;"
                           src="png/security.png" alt="Cyber Security">Cyber Security</img>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="Type = 'Teach Code'">
                      <img style="background: rgba(255,255,255.75); width:45px; height:45px;
                      border: 3px solid #FFB34C; border-radius: 10px; padding: 7px;"
                           src="png/teach.png" alt="Teach Code">Teach Code</img>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="Type = 'Alt Reality'">
                      <img style="background: rgba(255,255,255.75); width:45px; height:45px;
                      border: 3px solid #8D301D; border-radius: 10px; padding: 7px;"
                           src="png/vr.png" alt="Alternate Reality">Alt Reality</img>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="Type = 'Web Dev'">
                      <img style="background: rgba(255,255,255.75); width:45px; height:45px;
                      border: 3px solid #35405A; border-radius: 10px; padding: 7px;"
                              src="png/webdev.png" alt="Website Development">Web Dev</img>
                  </xsl:if >
                  <object hspace="20" style="font-weight: bold;"><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></object>
                  <object align="right" style="font-weight: bold;"><xsl:value-of select="Date"/></object>
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div>Event details go here</div>
                <br></br>
                <div><span style="color:Black; font-weight:1000; text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px grey;">Sponsor: </span><xsl:value-of select="Sponsor"/></div>
                <div><span style="color:Black; font-weight:1000; text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px grey;">Image: </span><xsl:value-of select="Image"/></div>
                <div><span style="color:Black; font-weight:1000; text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px grey;">Description: </span><xsl:value-of select="Description"/></div>
                <div><span style="color:Black; font-weight:1000; text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px grey;">Address: </span><xsl:value-of select="Location/Address"/></div>
                <div><span style="color:Black; font-weight:1000; text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px grey;">Room: </span><xsl:value-of select="Location/Room"/></div>
                <div><span style="color:Black; font-weight:1000; text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px grey;">Time: </span><xsl:value-of select="Time"/></div>
                <div><span style="color:Black; font-weight:1000; text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px grey;">RSVP: </span><xsl:value-of select="RSVP_Link"/></div>
                <div>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function initMap() {
                            var location = {lat: "&lt;xsl:value-of select="Location/Coordinates/LAT" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>",
                                            lng: "&lt;xsl:value-of select="Location/Coordinates/LON" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>"};
                            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                                zoom: 16,
                                center: location
                                });
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: location,
                                map: map
                            });
                        }
                    </script>
                    <script async="async" defer="defer"
                            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAJQ0BsjJqHv3AoJc35A&amp;callback=initMap">
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you don't mind ES6 you can use backticks

Comment: What is the problem? You have provided a snippet of XSLT. What does your XML look like, and why is the output not meeting your expectations? Can you provide a snippet of the current output and describe why it isn't meeting your expectations?

Comment: Shouldn't your `lat` and `lng` properties be numbers? Why wrap with quotes and make them strings?

Comment: Just added the XSL file, They are integers. Originally they weren't wrapped in quotes. I came across a solution that corrected the issues with quotes but apparently, it was a different issue.

Comment: The Javascript code `new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map')` only makes sense if there is an HTML element with an `id="map"` attribute somewhere, I don't find it. And obviously if you want to create several maps then you will have to set up several elements with different id values and adjust the Javascript.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52521343/how-to-pass-parameters-to-google-maps-initmap-in-xslt might help although I am not sure it solves the same problem, you will need to elaborate on whether you want to have several maps visible in several HTML elements at the same time.